# Mars crewed trip - earliest year technology was available?

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight

With the technology built for the Moon landings, would it have been possible to send people to Mars?

If no, what would have been the earliest year technology would have been available?

@Fred said 'moon landings relied on computers on Earth for guidance and landing'

In 1981, the Space Shuttle first launched; did it contain advanced-enough technology to not **require** assistance from ground control?

We do not **need** to produce anything on Mars; everything can be sent there ahead of time using unmanned missions.

Comment: One thing that made landing on the Moon in the 1960s less difficult was its proximity to Earth which enabled the use of nearly "primitive" computers on Earth to assist with guidance control & landing. I imagine with Mars being more distant, better onboard computers would be required than what was available in the 1970s.

Comment: @Fred light takes 1.3 seconds to moon; how was it assisted? What useful updates COULD be made with that latency?

Comment: My comment wasn't about latency. With the Moon-Earth proximity, if anything went wrong during a lunar mission it would have been easier & more timely to correct the issue because of that proximity. Computer technology at the time did allow for better computers onboard spacecraft & for spacecraft & crew to act independently of Earth to devise their own remedy; they relied on people & computers on Earth. A Mars mission would require the crew to potentially have more independence to remedy a bad situation. For that, good computers & software, onboard, would be required.

Comment: In my opinion we don't have the necessary technology yet. We know that propellants or fuel should be produced on Mars for return flight, but it is only theory and we did nothing like this on Mars. We need technology thoroughly tested on Mars.

Comment: To add to my point, Apollo lunar crews were only able to take slide rules with them to perform hand calculations. The [HP 35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-35) calculator was the first scientific hand held calculator produced. It was released in February 1972. Neither Apollo 16 or 17 had them. Their first use in Space was in July 1973 on Skylab 3.

Comment: @Fred would you say that the tech in Space Shuttle (1981) was definitely able to accomplish a crewed Mars mission?

Comment: @Uwe it doesn't have to be produced on Mars. We can send all the fuel for return trip.

Comment: The problem with getting to Mars is not the availability of computer technology; it is the time required to get there and the difficulty of keeping the crew alive for that time. You might enjoy watching former astronaut Stan Love's excellent presentation on this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fturU0u5KJo

Comment: @OrganicMarble if not technology, where is this difficulty in keeping crew alive?

Comment: Did you watch the presentation?

Comment: @Bob If the return fuel is not produced on Mars, we need an incredible big rocket to send the fuel there. A much bigger rocket than we have, about some hundreds to a thousand times more payload.

Comment: "what would have been the earliest year technology would have been available?" – I'm voting for ~2025.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm voting for much later than that. From realistic reports that I've read, sending humans to Mar now or in the near future is a one way suicide trip.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Let me be more precise: I believe that within the next few years, it will be possible to send humans to Mars, survive the landing and do a bit of science before they suffocate / starve / dehydrate to death. Whereas right now, I believe the best we can do is have them die during descent – the biggest payload we have ever landed successfully is ~1t, which I feel is to small to be a crew descent vehicle. Having people pulverized upon impact with the surface is *technically* also "sending people to Mars", though, so maybe that counts?

Comment: With enough money in 1960 you could have probably sent someone to Mars and back.

Comment: Theres an element which you need to address, which has significant weight on the answer - how much risk are you willing to assume for the successful return of the crew?  Would you be willing to accept a 50% loss from 2 launches?  80% loss from 5?  After all, the 1 success in those two scenarios is enough to fulfil your criteria...

Answer (score 1):

In March 1966 the American Institute of Astronautics and Aeronautics and the American Astronautical Society jointly convened the Stepping Stones to Mars conference, which envisioned a manned mission to Mars in 1986.

At that conference, [Ernst Stuhlinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Stuhlinger), one of Von Braun's team at Huntsville, produced a very detailed plan for a manned Mars mission using four spacecraft, each with a crew of four, to Mars.  The mission would use technology that was largely available at the time such as the NERVA engine (which was being developed in 1966 and was flight-ready when it was cancelled in 1973). [The full story is here](https://spaceflighthistory.blogspot.com/2016/12/nerva-electric-mars-mission-1966.html).

[Paul Swan presented the Avco/RAD](https://arstechnica.com/science/2012/04/nasas-1966-plan-for-a-mission-to-mars/) study, at the conference, which examined the process of investigation and exploration by a crewed mission.

David S. F. Portree has produced an [interesting history of Mars mission planning](https://history.nasa.gov/monograph21.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking the technology isn't available today, although it could have been available sooner if dedicated funding was done.

The Apollo program could not have reached Mars for a number of reasons. Life support was too limited, there wasn't enough propulsion, the lander couldn't land on the Mars, etc. At best a flyby could have been done of another planet, perhaps Venus, and there were concepts for sure out there.

The question you are really asking I think is at what year could we have started, say, an Apollo type effort and landed on Mars. The biggest challenges to landing on Mars are (In no order)

1. Life Support/ food
2. Building the lander and subsequent ascent vehicle
3. Building a habitat that can survive for months (Really closer to 20 for some paths)
4. A vehicle capable of launching all of this stuff and more to Mars.

Of these the single biggest obstacle is building the lander that will land on Mars. The current general path that every US mission has used to land on Mars involves a heat shield, parachute, and final either rocket power or airbags to finish the landing. None of these architectures would work with a human rated, mostly they can't use the parachute.

Life support has been in the neighborhood since we had continually inhabited space stations, of which the first was MIR.

The knowledge of Martian weather and surviving on Mars is likely the trickiest bit. The Viking orbiters and landers did discover a lot, but I don't really feel like we would have had a good Mars mission until after MGS.

Putting it all together really requires 2 different plans. A radically accelerated schedule could have been started as early as 1976 with the Viking missions and maybe had a mission land in the mid-1980s. A more measured approach could have been started with MGS and been successful in the early 2000s.

Comment: "the lander couldn't land on the Moon" ?? Also, re life support: Earth orbit stations are continuously resupplied, not an option for a trip to Mars.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Woops, should have been Mars.  Agree with the continually resupplied portion, in theory with the launch of enough supplies it would be possible on Mars, but...

Answer (score 0):

It’s impossible to say with any accuracy because it’s an alternative history question that depends on all manner of complex assumptions about technological development in different areas as well as finance and politics.

Assuming that a Human Mars mission might be possible by 2029 would put it 60 years ahead of the Moon landings. Through much of that period the US human space program has been lacking true sustained long term vision and goals. It has been subject to all manner of political, budgetary and other short term influences causing what can only be described as derangement.

Congress had and still has no interest in space policy goals only aerospace jobs and has continually tried to second guess which space policy goals would produce the right blend of jobs for big aerospace companies in key states. So the aerospace industry jobs tails wags the space policy goal dog.

The result has been the hugely expensive shuttle and ISS, plans for Mars, plans for a human visit to an asteroid, at least 2 different initiatives to return to the Moon and the SLS.

In order to have advanced faster, this madness would need to be written out of the story somehow. The 90 day report in 1989 put a 400 billion dollar price tag on a human Mars landing back when 400 billion dollars was a lot of money. This made the whole idea impractical and it was shelved.

What was needed then was someone to realize that the primary problem was one of affordability, cost reduction and reuse not just technological development. The other thing needed would have been some overriding political driving force (perhaps the Chinese had already reached Mars) that would put the nation on a virtual war footing and open the money spigots to achieve the goal of landing humans on Mars.

With that perhaps the rate of progress might have been doubled so instead of the 40 years of dithering between 1989 to 2029 we might have had 20 years of massive investment and dedicated hard work to a single minded goal landing the first humans on Mars by 2009.

That’s my guess and IMO given the huge number of variables that’s about as good as it gets. The likelihood of such a scenario is however another matter.

Comment: If it costs 400bil in 1990s, why isn't it at least as expensive for SpaceX?

Comment: Because the 90 day report was based on taking everything needed for the whole trip including all of the return propellants and IIRC they were planning on storable hypergolics which are lower performance than LOX which would have meant a humongous "Battlestar Galactica" style mission. It would also have thrown every single booster used into the ocean including all those required to provide propellent in orbit for the outbound mission and the propellant required to send the return propellant to Mars and and...